# Triggering a future event based on a current event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, events, data-structures, queuing

i would like to trigger an event sometime in the future based on an event that is currently happening. I do not expect the volume to be too high, so i care a lot more about simplicity than performance.

For example:

- event A happens. i need event B to happen a day later (not time critical)
- system stores a record of event in db
- ongoing process looks through the db, and executes the event Bs that are ready, and removes them from db

Does this make sense? I am using Ruby on rails -  I imagine this  is a fairly common usecase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DelayedJob](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem. Refer to this [screen-cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it absolutely makes sense :). You should be probably looking at a Scheduler or a process that runs in the background. Take a look [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/background-processes?s[]=background&s[]=jobs) and [here](http://inventivelabs.com.au/weblog/post/scheduling-periodic-tasks-in-a-rails-application/)

Basically, whenever you finish executing your event A, you will be putting an entry in the database with a field indicating when it should run. As you say, your ongoing process which should be scheduled to run in the background can either be scheduled in steps or do a polling and query the DB and carry on from there like you've said.